# PC drawing power from screen?

Tags: display, desktop-computer, vga, dvi

I have a PC connected to a screen. Recently (over the past 5 weeks) the screen has been physically dying, as if the power had been unplugged.

What I have tested:

- I have tested different screens, of different models.
- Power source is not tripping, I have tested multiple power points and multiple cables.
- I have tested different VGA and DVI cables (the PC and screen do not have other options).

Regardless of these changes, the screen dies, and will not turn back on unless I physically unplug the power cable and reconnect it. Again - this occurs regardless of the power source.

The only difference I have noticed, is how long I leave the screen unplugged for. E.g. if I unplug in for 2 seconds, it will remain on for 20-30 seconds before dying. If I leave it unplugged for 30 seconds, it will remain on for 2-3 minutes.

The only thing that could be causing this is the PC, via the VGA/DVI connection. Is this a possibility? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds like a capacitor issue with the display.

Comment: A failing power supply in the display could be the cause of this. Possibly the high-voltage supply of the backlight, as these are often the first components to fail in an aging display. Does the display's power LED stay on?

Comment: You don't have an Eco setting on the monitor's inbuilt configuration menu do you?

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing that could be causing this is the PC, via the VGA/DVI
> connection. Is this a possibility?

No. Not that I have ever seen. The monitor inside (power supply or main monitor board) may be dying.  Replace the monitor.

Normal computer / monitor operation will not result in what you see.

It is possible the connection inside to the monitor (wires in the pins) has become intermittent or some other fault causing the issue (possibly crossed up but that seems unlikely).

In this event you would need to get the computer professionally serviced

Make certain you have the correct connecting cable between computer and monitor.

Comment: I did that - that was the first thing I did.

Comment: Possible the connection inside is intermittent or otherwise faulty causing the issue.